# How to use the cweave and ctangle programs that come with MikTeX?

Tags: cweb

I'm interested in using CWEB with LaTeX on Windows.  Today I discovered my MikTeX installation comes with two interesting programs, cweave and ctangle.  Are they Knuth and Levy's CWEB?  When I try to run them, I get the following problem:

```
%cweave.exe cwebsync.w_h
This is CWEAVE, Version 3.64 (MiKTeX 2.9.6960)
Sorry, but c:\emacs\miktex\texmfs\install\miktex\bin\cweave.exe did not succeed.
The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:
  c:\emacs\miktex\texmfs\data\miktex\log\cweave.log
%
```

The log file reveals the following:

```
%cat c:\emacs\miktex\texmfs\data\miktex\log\cweave.log
[...]
2019-02-18 21:44:44,561-0300 INFO  cweave - starting with command line: c:\emacs\miktex\texmfs\install\miktex\bin\cweave.exe cwebsync.w_h
2019-02-18 21:44:44,644-0300 FATAL cweave - MiKTeX encountered an internal error.
2019-02-18 21:44:44,645-0300 FATAL cweave - Info: path="."
2019-02-18 21:44:44,645-0300 FATAL cweave - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\Session\miktex.cpp
2019-02-18 21:44:44,646-0300 FATAL cweave - Line: 675
2019-02-18 21:44:44,656-0300 INFO  cweave - finishing with exit code 1
%
```

I've seen this type of internal error before --- my MikTeX is the portable one and not everything works out of the box with this MikTeX portable version.  So perhaps that's the same problem here.  Nevertheless: should I bother with these programs from the MikTex installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running a portable version should not be the issue if the miktex\bin is on path and the texmf's are well structured, I know because if I run from anywhere in the system my portable usb copy

`ctangle C:\Users\myname\Desktop\cweb_tar\examples\wordtest.w`
I correctly get wordtest.c and if I cweave I get the 30k of wordtest.tex

I did get an **error message when I did not give the absolute address** and sensibly did not run from a path with spaces etc.

Apart from the CTAN files an interesting related collection is at http://www.literateprogramming.com/cweb_download.html and of course the main site https://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~knuth/cweb.html